# How to use jQuery with Flask-WTF for real-time word count in TextAreaField?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would like to add a real-time word count feature to a TextAreaField and have determined this can be done using jQuery. I am basing my code off of the following example:

```html
<html lang="en">
 
<head>
    <script src=
        "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js">
    </script>
</head>
 
<body>
    <h1>Example Word Count</h1>
    <input type="text" id="word-count" />
    <input type="text" id="feedback" disabled />
 
    <script>
        function wordCount(field) {
            var number = 0;
 
            // Split the value of input by
            // space to count the words
            var matches = $(field).val().split(" ");
 
            // Count number of words
            number = matches.filter(function (word) {
                return word.length > 0;
            }).length;
 
            // Final number of words
            $("#feedback").val(number);
        }
 
        $(function () {
            $("input[type='text']:not(:disabled)")
            .each(function () {
                var input = "#" + this.id;
 
                // Count words when keyboard
                // key is released
                $(this).keyup(function () {
                    wordCount(input);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
 
</html>
```

Being very new to jQuery, I am not sure how to incorporate my Flask-WTF form so that the words typed in the form are then counted in the box to the side.

Here is the excerpt from my form.py:

```
class DeclineForm(FlaskForm):
    feedback = TextAreaField("",validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=15)], render_kw={"placeholder": "Don't forget to include at least 15 words"})
    submit = SubmitField("Decline")
```

Here is my current HTML code for that form:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-decline-{{ submission.id }}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">Decline</button>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <div class="collapse" id="collapse-decline-{{ submission.id }}">
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ decline_form.feedback.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                {% if decline_form.feedback.errors %}
                {{ decline_form.feedback(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    {% for error in decline_form.feedback.errors %}
                    <span>{{ error }}</span>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
                {% else %}
                    <input type="text" id="word-count" disabled/>
                    {{ decline_form.feedback(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                {% endif %}
                </div>
                <script>
                    function wordCount(field) {
                        var number = 0;
                        var matches = $(field).val().split(" ");
                        number = matches.filter(function (word) {
                            return word.length > 0;
                        }).length;
                        $("#word-count").val(number);
                    }
                         
                    $(function () {
                        $("input[type='text']:not(:disabled)")
                        .each(function () {
                            var input = "#" + this.id;
                                $(this).keyup(function () {
                                    wordCount(input);
                                });
                            });
                        });
                </script>
            <input type="hidden" name="submission-id" value="{{submission.id}}"></input>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="review-submission" value="Decline"> 
            </input>
        </div>
    </form>
```

How can I update the jQuery code to implement my Flask-WTF form `{{ decline_form.feedback(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the jQuery selector `$("input[type='text']:not(:disabled)")` in order to match your `textarea` as you don't use an `<input>`.

```
$("textarea")
```

Also, you need to give an id to your `textarea` field, I'm not sure how WTForms handle the `id` attribute. It might be automatic, just be sure that in the rendered HTML your text area have an `id` attribute.

Check the documentation if not: https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/#the-field-base-class

Comment: Thanks for the answer - Flask WTF does add automatic id's. All I had to do was add the "#name_of_id" to the $(), so in the end it looked like this:

`$(#"feedback")`